# Ubuntu 16.04 python3.5: PyAudio 0.2.9 or later is required (found version 0.2.8)

Tags: python-3.5, ubuntu-16.04

that's my first question here.

I have a problem with python3.5 and PyAudio on my Ubuntu 16.04:

**What type of problem I have**
Currently I'm writing on a program that uses the speech_recognition library in python.
And if I call my script (`python3 processor.py`), it says the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "processor.py", line 143, in <module>
  main()
File "processor.py", line 132, in main
  with sp_reco.Microphone() as source:
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 55, in __init__
  self.pyaudio_module = self.get_pyaudio()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/speech_recognition/__init__.py", line 88, in get_pyaudio
  raise AttributeError("PyAudio 0.2.9 or later is required (found version {0})".format(pyaudio.__version__))
AttributeError: PyAudio 0.2.9 or later is required (found version 0.2.8)
```

Checking existing pip3 modules with `pip3 list` gave me the following:

```
PyAudio (0.2.9)
```

And I don't know why speech_recognition says the found version is 0.2.8

And it works if I type `python3` in the console and type in the shown python console `import pyaudio`
My script works fully, if I use the `python` command

**Screenshot pip3 list**

[image: pip3 list screenshot]

Comment: Please can you share your pip3 list's screen shots here? I don't think that Ubuntu 16.04 has python3-pyaudio v 0.2.9. Till now all the Ubuntu releases have only got Pyaudio v 0.2.8 build 2. You can see here,
[Pyaudio versions available for Ubuntu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IY671.png)

Comment: Screenshot added. As you can see I have PyAudio  (0.2.9)!